# Retornar os dados para a View usando o Json.net ou javascript– asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json

Estou precisando retornar os dados para preencher um script,

```html
        public JsonResult BuscaImagens()
        {
            List<Object> resultado = new List<object>();
            resultado.Add(new
            {
                IdImagem = 1,
                URL = "~/Content/img/galeriaimagens/sl1.jpg"
            });
            resultado.Add(new
            {
                IdImagem = 2,
                URL = "~/Content/img/galeriaimagens/sl2.jpg"
            });
            resultado.Add(new
            {
                IdImagem = 3,
                URL = "~/Content/img/galeriaimagens/sl3.jpg"
            });
            return Json(resultado, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Agora tenho:

```html
        public ActionResult LerDadosJson()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Na View LerDadosJson:

```html
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Home/BuscaImagens",
            success: function (dados) {
                $(dados).each(function (i) {
                    document.writeln("<p>Id: " + dados[i].IdImagem + " | URL: " + dados[i].URL + "</p>")
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Retorno das Informações está assim
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso deste formato que está dento do  initialPreview e initialPreviewConfig:

```
<script>

  $("#Image1").fileinput({
    uploadUrl: "@Url.Action("upload", "Home")",
    uploadAsync: false,
    minFileCount: 2,
    maxFileCount: 5,
    overwriteInitial: false,
    initialPreview: [
        "<img style='height:160px' src=@Url.Content("~/Content/img/galeriaimagens/sl1.jpg")>",
        "<img style='height:160px' src=@Url.Content("~/Content/img/galeriaimagens/sl1.jpg")>",
        "<img style='height:160px' src=@Url.Content("~/Content/img/galeriaimagens/sl1.jpg")>",
        "<img style='height:160px' src=@Url.Content("~/Content/img/galeriaimagens/sl1.jpg")>",
    ],
    initialPreviewConfig: [
        { caption: "Food-1.jpg", size: 329892, width: "120px", url: "@Url.Action("remover", "Home")", key: 1 },
        { caption: "Food-2.jpg", size: 872378, width: "120px", url: "@Url.Action("remover", "Home")", key: 2 },
        { caption: "Food-3.jpg", size: 632762, width: "120px", url: "@Url.Action("remover", "Home")", key: 3 },
        { caption: "Food-4.jpg", size: 632762, width: "120px", url: "@Url.Action("remover", "Home")", key: 4 },
    ],
    uploadExtraData: {
        img_key: "1000",
        img_keywords: "happy, nature",
    }
});
$("#Image1").on("filepredelete", function (jqXHR) {
    var abort = true;
    if (confirm("Tem certeza de que deseja apagar esta imagem?")) {
        abort = false;
    }
    return abort; // you can also send any data/object that you can receive on `filecustomerror` event
});
</script>
```

Comment: Impossível responder sua pergunta sem saber qual o tipo de dados que `tbuscar.ListarTodos();` retorna! Seria interessante também se postasse um exemplo do JSON que está esperando.

Comment: Vou ajustar a pergunta, um momento

Comment: @Loudenvier, ajustado, agradeço

Comment: Você está recebendo o que está passando como resposta. Você passa `"~/Content/img/galeriaimagens/sl1.jpg"` e recebe isso no cliente. Você quer converter isso para uma URL válida e enviar isso para o cliente? É essa a dúvida?

Comment: quero adicionar no initialPreview as imagens

Comment: Sim, mas qual o resultado do JSON que vc quer de verdade? Se você monta o initialPreview no servidor, pode usar o "~\url", mas se vai montar no cliente já tem que passar essa URL "resolvida". O seu json está indo corretamente para o cliente no BuscaImagens, mas o URL é que está indo errado, ao que me parece. Tente fazer `URL = Page.ResolveUrl("~/Content/img/galeriaimagens/sl1.jpg")`

Comment: @Loudenvier, a minha ideia seria concatenar o resultado dentro uma variável e adicionar o resultado dentro do initialPreview

Comment: Entendi, quando chegar em casa posto um resposta... Mas nem deve precisar usar JSON

Comment: @Loudenvier, agradeço o empenho em me ajudar nesta dúvida

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para criar o script já com o `initialPreview` preenchido não será necessário criar um método que retorne JSON. Será mais eficiente modificar a *View* que hoje gera a página para utilizar uma modelo, e nesse modelo gerar esse script dinamicamente. Existem várias formas de se implementar esse resultado. Vou fazer a mais imediatista primeiro.

**ViewBag**

Vamos preencher o `ViewBag`, um item dinâmico que pode ser preenchido com tudo quanto e tipo de dados e está disponível para a engine de renderização da página, no caso o Razor. Como estamos usando essa forma mais simples de passar dados para a View, adicionei a classe Imagem **diretamente** no `HomeController` (no seu caso o nome do *controller* e da *action* certamente serão diferentes!):

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public class Imagem
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
    }

    public ActionResult Index() {
        // usando ViewBag... (propriedade dinâmica)
        ViewBag.Images = new List<Imagem> {
            new Imagem { Id = 1, Url = Url.Content("~/Content/img/galeriaimagens/sl1.jpg") },
            new Imagem { Id = 2, Url = Url.Content("~/Content/img/galeriaimagens/sl2.jpg") },
            new Imagem { Id = 3, Url = Url.Content("~/Content/img/galeriaimagens/sl3.jpg") },
        };
        return View();
    }
```

E então na view usamos o ViewBag.Images para renderizar a lista de urls que colocaremos no *initial preview*. Note que você deverá ajustar a cláusula `using` no início do script para usar o controller onde você definiu a classe `Imagem`:

```
@using SO_InitialPreviewMVC.Controllers;
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    // estou já convertendo para o tipo específico para facilitar mais embaixo
    var imgs = ViewBag.Images as List<HomeController.Imagem>;
}

<script>

  $("#Image1").fileinput({
    uploadUrl: "@Url.Action("upload", "Home")",
    uploadAsync: false,
    minFileCount: 2,
    maxFileCount: 5,
    overwriteInitial: false,
    initialPreview: [
        @* Aqui using string.Join para montar os itens do array, tem um milhão de formas de fazer isso! *@
        @Html.Raw(string.Join(",\r\n        ", 
            imgs.Select(img => "\"<img style='height:160px' src='" + img.Url + "'>\"")))
    ],
    initialPreviewConfig: [
        { caption: "Food-1.jpg", size: 329892, width: "120px", url: "@Url.Action("remover", "Home")", key: 1 },
        { caption: "Food-2.jpg", size: 872378, width: "120px", url: "@Url.Action("remover", "Home")", key: 2 },
        { caption: "Food-3.jpg", size: 632762, width: "120px", url: "@Url.Action("remover", "Home")", key: 3 },
        { caption: "Food-4.jpg", size: 632762, width: "120px", url: "@Url.Action("remover", "Home")", key: 4 },
    ],
    uploadExtraData: {
            img_key: "1000",
        img_keywords: "happy, nature",
    }
  });
</script>
```

O restante do código da view foi omitido... Deixei o suficiente para que se entenda onde foram feitas as mudanças.

**View Model**

Essa é o que eu indicaria como a melhor forma. Vamos criar um modelo que chamaremos de **View Model** porque ele é o modelo da "visão" e não do negócio. Ele é usado para facilitar a renderização da view e até mesmo transportar informações de validação (em casos raros) e outras coisas mais.

Vamos adicionar a classe HomeViewModel no diretório Models da sua solução:

```
public class HomeViewModel
{
    public HomeViewModel() {
        // apenas para garantir que NUNCA seja nulo! Facilica código na view
        PreviewImages = new List<Imagem>();
    }
    public List<Imagem> PreviewImages { get; set; }
}
```

*Adicione no namespace da sua aplicação! Use no lugar de "Home" o nome da sua View para manter a consistência!!!*

Adicione no Models a mesma classe Imagem (que tiramos do HomeController, já que ela agora será usada pelo nosso `HomeViewModel` e provavelmente outros *view models*!):

```
public class Imagem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

Modifique o método do controller para passar o modelo para a view fortemente tipada:

```
... 
// adicione o using do seus Models (seu namespace será outro!!!)
using SO_InitialPreviewMVC.Models;
...
public ActionResult Index() {
    // usando um modelo específico para a view
    var model  = new HomeViewModel { 
        PreviewImages = new List<Imagem> {
            new Imagem { Id = 1, Url = Url.Content("~/Content/img/galeriaimagens/sl1.jpg") },
            new Imagem { Id = 2, Url = Url.Content("~/Content/img/galeriaimagens/sl2.jpg") },
            new Imagem { Id = 3, Url = Url.Content("~/Content/img/galeriaimagens/sl3.jpg") },
        }
    };
    // passamos o modelo criado para a view
    return View(model);
}
```

Agora modifique a view para que ela seja fortemente tipada:

```
@model SO_InitialPreviewMVC.Models.HomeViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<script>

  $("#Image1").fileinput({
    uploadUrl: "@Url.Action("upload", "Home")",
    uploadAsync: false,
    minFileCount: 2,
    maxFileCount: 5,
    overwriteInitial: false,
    initialPreview: [
        @* Aqui using string.Join para montar os itens do array, tem um milhão de formas de fazer isso! *@
        @Html.Raw(string.Join(",\r\n        ",
            Model.PreviewImages.Select(img => "\"<img style='height:160px' src='" + img.Url + "'>\"")))
    ],
```

*Novamente, o namespace do `@model` será outro!*

Veja que não usamos mais um campo dinâmico como o `ViewBag`e temos até sugestão de complementação de código ao digitarmos `Model.`... Você verá que aparecerá a propriedade `PreviewImages`.

**Resultado**
O markup gerado para ambas as soluções é igual e segue abaixo a parte apenas do `<script>` em si:

```
<script>

  $("#Image1").fileinput({
    uploadUrl: "/Home/upload",
    uploadAsync: false,
    minFileCount: 2,
    maxFileCount: 5,
    overwriteInitial: false,
    initialPreview: [

        "<img style='height:160px' src='/Content/img/galeriaimagens/sl1.jpg'>",
        "<img style='height:160px' src='/Content/img/galeriaimagens/sl2.jpg'>",
        "<img style='height:160px' src='/Content/img/galeriaimagens/sl3.jpg'>"
    ],
    initialPreviewConfig: [
        { caption: "Food-1.jpg", size: 329892, width: "120px", url: "/Home/remover", key: 1 },
        { caption: "Food-2.jpg", size: 872378, width: "120px", url: "/Home/remover", key: 2 },
        { caption: "Food-3.jpg", size: 632762, width: "120px", url: "/Home/remover", key: 3 },
        { caption: "Food-4.jpg", size: 632762, width: "120px", url: "/Home/remover", key: 4 },
    ],
    uploadExtraData: {
            img_key: "1000",
        img_keywords: "happy, nature",
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Loudenvier, a sua resposta foi excelente, você tem um grande conhecimento e fico muito grato por sua ajuda, mais se possível, veja se você poderia complementar a sua resposta, fiz um novo poste para não ficar extenso este aqui, eu preciso configurar o initialPreviewConfig também, e preciso trazer os caminhos das imagens que estão na tabela no banco de dados.
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/161071/listando-o-retorno-de-um-viewbag-para-a-view