# Listando o retorno de um ViewBag para a View?

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Seguindo as instruções deste poste ([Retornar os dados para a View usando o Json.net ou javascript– asp.net mvc](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/160774/retornar-os-dados-para-a-view-usando-o-json-net-ou-javascript-asp-net-mvc)) respondida pelo Loudenvier

ficou assim:

Classe:

```html
public class TB_RECEBE_IMAGENS
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long Size { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:( aqui eu preciso trazer os registros , caminho das imagens que está no banco, a dúvida está aqui, os dados do "listar")

//.......................................................

```
    public ActionResult VisualizaImagens()
    {
        var tbuscar = new CadastroImagemAplicacao();
        var listar = tbuscar.ListarTodos();

        //preencer os dados a baixo com o que vem do banco, 

        var model = new HomeViewModel
        {
            PreviewImages = new List<TB_RECEBE_IMAGENS> {
        new TB_RECEBE_IMAGENS { Id = 1, Url = Url.Content("~/Content/img/galeriaimagens/sl1.jpg") },
        new TB_RECEBE_IMAGENS { Id = 2, Url = Url.Content("~/Content/img/galeriaimagens/sl2.jpg") },
        new TB_RECEBE_IMAGENS { Id = 3, Url = Url.Content("~/Content/img/galeriaimagens/sl3.jpg") },
        new TB_RECEBE_IMAGENS { Id = 4, Url = Url.Content("~/Content/img/galeriaimagens/sl4.jpg") },
         },
            // size será preenchido depois (mas se vier do banco de dados, PREENCHA aqui para evitar perda de performance
            InitialPreviewConfigImages = new List<TB_RECEBE_IMAGENS> {
        new TB_RECEBE_IMAGENS { Id = 1, Url = Url.Content("~/Content/img/galeriaimagens/sl1.jpg"), Name = "Food-1.jpg" },
        new TB_RECEBE_IMAGENS { Id = 2, Url = Url.Content("~/Content/img/galeriaimagens/sl2.jpg"), Name = "Food-2.jpg" },
        new TB_RECEBE_IMAGENS { Id = 3, Url = Url.Content("~/Content/img/galeriaimagens/sl3.jpg"), Name = "Food-3.jpg" },
        new TB_RECEBE_IMAGENS { Id = 4, Url = Url.Content("~/Content/img/galeriaimagens/sl4.jpg"), Name = "Food-4.jpg" },
        }

        };
        FindFileSizes(model.InitialPreviewConfigImages);
        return View(model);
    }

    private void FindFileSizes(List<TB_RECEBE_IMAGENS> imgs)
    {
        foreach (var img in imgs)
        {
            // é preciso converter o caminho relativo da URL em um caminho físico no servidor
            var serverPath = Server.MapPath(img.Url);
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(serverPath))
            {
                img.Size = new System.IO.FileInfo(serverPath).Length;
            }
        }
    }

    //.......................................................
```

Na View ficou assim:

```
@model Projeto.FileInput.Models.HomeViewModel


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "VisualizaImagens";
}




<div class="container">
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <h1>Sending only 1 image</h1>
        <input id="Image1" type="file" name="imagens01[]" class="file" data-overwrite-initial="false" data-min-file-count="1">
    </form>
</div>



<script>

    $("#Image1").fileinput({
        uploadUrl: "@Url.Action("upload", "Home")",
        uploadAsync: false,
        minFileCount: 2,
        maxFileCount: 5,
        overwriteInitial: false,
        initialPreview: [
            @* Aqui using string.Join para montar os itens do array, tem um milhão de formas de fazer isso! *@
            @Html.Raw(string.Join(",\r\n        ",
            Model.PreviewImages.Select(img => "\"<img style='height:160px' src='" + img.Url + "'>\"")))
        ],
        initialPreviewConfig: [
        @* poderia ser feito com string.Join, mas resolvi mostrar outra forma com foreach e < text > *@
        @foreach (var img in Model.InitialPreviewConfigImages) {
            <text>{ caption: "@img.Name", size: @img.Size, width: "120px", url: "@Url.Action("remover", "Home")", key: @img.Id },</text>
        }
    ],
    uploadExtraData: {
                img_key: "1000",
        img_keywords: "happy, nature",
    }
        });
</script>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Respondi sem usar `ViewBag`. Usei o modelo para ficar mais fácil trabalhar, mas é bastante simples modificar para usar `ViewBag`.

Comment: Talvez seja mais interessante criar uma outra pergunta verificando como listar os dados das imagens como você quer, senão a resposta aqui pode ficar muito longa! Coloque lá o código de acesso ao banco, as tabelas, etc. Assim podemos responder dentro de um escopo mais bem definido. Posta pelo menos o código de `CadastroDeImagens.ListarTodos`, aqui nessa pergunta (se preferir manter tudo num só lugar), ou na outra.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/161184/retorno-para-view-de-duas-tabelas-usando-homeviewmodel

Fiz uma nova pergunta, agradeço

Answer (score 1):

Para preencher o `InitialPreviewConfig` deve ser utilizada a mesma ideia do que foi feito com o `initialPreview`. Adicionamos os campos `Size` e `Name` para enviar no novo campo (não precisamos adicionar valores para esses dados no `initialPreview` porque a tela/página (view) não utiliza esses dados. Poderíamos até, para sermos puristas, criar dois modelos para cada tipo, mas acho totalmente desnecessário (por enquanto).

Uma dificuldade que ocorrerá é o cálculo do tamanho do arquivo, porque exigirá que se converta o caminho relativo de uma imagem para um caminho físico no servidor para então pegar o tamanho do arquivo usando uma API do .NET para manipulação de arquivos. Isso pode ser evitado se o tamanho do arquivo já estiver cadastrado no banco de dados.

*Mantive a nomenclatura utilizada anteriormente porque a nomenclatura utilizada na pergunta foge, completamente, das orientação para nomes de classes e métodos em C#.*

O código modificado fica como se segue:

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index() {
    var model  = new HomeViewModel { 
        PreviewImages = new List<Imagem> {
            new Imagem { Id = 1, Url = Url.Content("~/Content/img/galeriaimagens/sl1.jpg") },
            new Imagem { Id = 2, Url = Url.Content("~/Content/img/galeriaimagens/sl2.jpg") },
            new Imagem { Id = 3, Url = Url.Content("~/Content/img/galeriaimagens/sl3.jpg") },                
            new Imagem { Id = 4, Url = Url.Content("~/Content/img/galeriaimagens/sl4.jpg") },
        },
        // size será preenchido depois (mas se vier do banco de dados, PREENCHA aqui para evitar perda de performance
        InitialPreviewConfigImages = new List<Imagem> {
            new Imagem { Id = 1, Url = Url.Content("~/Content/img/galeriaimagens/sl1.jpg"), Name = "Food-1.jpg" },
            new Imagem { Id = 2, Url = Url.Content("~/Content/img/galeriaimagens/sl2.jpg"), Name = "Food-2.jpg" },
            new Imagem { Id = 3, Url = Url.Content("~/Content/img/galeriaimagens/sl3.jpg"), Name = "Food-3.jpg" },
            new Imagem { Id = 4, Url = Url.Content("~/Content/img/galeriaimagens/sl4.jpg"), Name = "Food-4.jpg" },
        }
    };
    FindFileSizes(model.InitialPreviewConfigImages);
    return View(model);
}

private void FindFileSizes(List<Imagem> imgs) {
    foreach (var img in imgs) {
        // é preciso converter o caminho relativo da URL em um caminho físico no servidor
        var serverPath = Server.MapPath(img.Url);
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(serverPath)) {
            img.Size = new System.IO.FileInfo(serverPath).Length;
        }
    }
}
```

Lembre-se que os dados vindo de um banco de dados deverão ser carregados, dinamicamente, de lá (se tiver o tamanho dos arquivos já armazenado, nem precisará chamar `FindFileSizes`).

**ViewModel**

```
public class HomeViewModel
{
    public HomeViewModel() {
        // apenas para garantir que NUNCA seja nulo! Facilica código na view
        PreviewImages = new List<Imagem>();
        InitialPreviewConfigImages = new List<Imagem>();
    }
    public List<Imagem> PreviewImages { get; set; }
    public List<Imagem> InitialPreviewConfigImages { get; set; }
}
```

**Classe Imagem**

```
public class Imagem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long Size { get; set; }
}
```

**Código da View**

```
@model SO_InitialPreviewMVC.Models.HomeViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<script>

    $("#Image1").fileinput({
        uploadUrl: "@Url.Action("upload", "Home")",
        uploadAsync: false,
        minFileCount: 2,
        maxFileCount: 5,
        overwriteInitial: false,
        initialPreview: [
            @* Aqui using string.Join para montar os itens do array, tem um milhão de formas de fazer isso! *@
            @Html.Raw(string.Join(",\r\n        ",
            Model.PreviewImages.Select(img => "\"<img style='height:160px' src='" + img.Url + "'>\"")))
        ],
        initialPreviewConfig: [
        @* poderia ser feito com string.Join, mas resolvi mostrar outra forma com foreach e < text > *@
        @foreach (var img in Model.InitialPreviewConfigImages) {
            <text>{ caption: "@img.Name", size: @img.Size, width: "120px", url: "@Url.Action("remover", "Home")", key: @img.Id },</text>
        }
    ],
    uploadExtraData: {
                img_key: "1000",
        img_keywords: "happy, nature",
    }
        });
</script>
```

**Resultado**

```
<script>

    $("#Image1").fileinput({
        uploadUrl: "/Home/upload",
        uploadAsync: false,
        minFileCount: 2,
        maxFileCount: 5,
        overwriteInitial: false,
        initialPreview: [

            "<img style='height:160px' src='/Content/img/galeriaimagens/sl1.jpg'>",
        "<img style='height:160px' src='/Content/img/galeriaimagens/sl2.jpg'>",
        "<img style='height:160px' src='/Content/img/galeriaimagens/sl3.jpg'>",
        "<img style='height:160px' src='/Content/img/galeriaimagens/sl4.jpg'>"
        ],
        initialPreviewConfig: [
            { caption: "Food-1.jpg", size: 0, width: "120px", url: "/Home/remover", key: 1 },
            { caption: "Food-2.jpg", size: 0, width: "120px", url: "/Home/remover", key: 2 },
            { caption: "Food-3.jpg", size: 0, width: "120px", url: "/Home/remover", key: 3 },
            { caption: "Food-4.jpg", size: 0, width: "120px", url: "/Home/remover", key: 4 },
    ],
    uploadExtraData: {
                img_key: "1000",
        img_keywords: "happy, nature",
    }
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Loudenvier, mais uma resposta fantástica, eu não tenho palavras para agradecer a sua ajuda, se você me cobrasse eu até pagava pela resposta porque você está me ajudando demais,  tudo deu certo, conforme você descreve no exemplo, só estou com dificuldade em pegar os dados do banco para preencher esta tabela Imagens, visto que são os mesmos campos. ajuste a dúvida com o resultado final e com retorno do banco "listar" que tem os mesmos campos que preciso adicionar

Comment: @itasouza essa resposta resolveu seu problama? Fiquei sem saber o resultado porque você não aceitou a resposta! Tem algo que possa ajudar ainda? Se não tiver, marca a resposta para que saibam que te ajudou!