# Retorno para View de duas tabelas usando HomeViewModel?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Tenho a situação seguinte, na minha pasta Models, tenho:

```html
public class HomeViewModel
{


    public HomeViewModel()
    {
        // apenas para garantir que NUNCA seja nulo! Facilica código na view
        PreviewImages = new List<Generico.Dominio.TB_IMAGEN_PERFIL>();
        InitialPreviewConfigImages = new List<Generico.Dominio.TB_IMAGEN_PERFIL>();
        User = new Generico.Dominio.TB_USUARIO();
    }

    //imagem do perfil do usuário 
    public List<Generico.Dominio.TB_IMAGEN_PERFIL> PreviewImages { get; set; }
    public List<Generico.Dominio.TB_IMAGEN_PERFIL> InitialPreviewConfigImages { get; set; }
    public Generico.Dominio.TB_USUARIO User { get; set; }


}
```

Quero trazer a opção de cadastro junto com a opção de galeria de imagem:
Na minha view hoje eu tenho um cadastro normal:

@model Generico.Dominio.TB_USUARIO

//dados do cadastro na view

//dados da galeria de foto na View

Na controller tenho:

```html
//:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
        public ActionResult ConsultaCadastroUsuarioCompleto(int id)
        {

            try
            {

                var tbuscar = new UsuarioAplicacao();
                TB_USUARIO  tbtabela = tbuscar.ListarPoId(id);

                var model = new HomeViewModel
                {
                    User = tbtabela,
                    PreviewImages = new List<Generico.Dominio.TB_IMAGEN_PERFIL> {
                    new Generico.Dominio.TB_IMAGEN_PERFIL { Id = 1, Url = Url.Content("~/Content/img/galeriaimagens/sl1.jpg") },
                    new Generico.Dominio.TB_IMAGEN_PERFIL { Id = 2, Url = Url.Content("~/Content/img/galeriaimagens/sl2.jpg") },
                    new Generico.Dominio.TB_IMAGEN_PERFIL { Id = 3, Url = Url.Content("~/Content/img/galeriaimagens/sl3.jpg") },
                    new Generico.Dominio.TB_IMAGEN_PERFIL { Id = 4, Url = Url.Content("~/Content/img/galeriaimagens/sl4.jpg") },
                     },
                    // size será preenchido depois (mas se vier do banco de dados, PREENCHA aqui para evitar perda de performance
                    InitialPreviewConfigImages = new List<Generico.Dominio.TB_IMAGEN_PERFIL> {
                    new Generico.Dominio.TB_IMAGEN_PERFIL { Id = 1, Url = Url.Content("~/Content/img/galeriaimagens/sl1.jpg"), Name = "Food-1.jpg" },
                    new Generico.Dominio.TB_IMAGEN_PERFIL { Id = 2, Url = Url.Content("~/Content/img/galeriaimagens/sl2.jpg"), Name = "Food-2.jpg" },
                    new Generico.Dominio.TB_IMAGEN_PERFIL { Id = 3, Url = Url.Content("~/Content/img/galeriaimagens/sl3.jpg"), Name = "Food-3.jpg" },
                    new Generico.Dominio.TB_IMAGEN_PERFIL { Id = 4, Url = Url.Content("~/Content/img/galeriaimagens/sl4.jpg"), Name = "Food-4.jpg" },
                    }

                };
                FindFileSizes(model.InitialPreviewConfigImages);


                return View(model);

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                TempData["Erro"] = "Erro ao Alterar Registro.";
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "CadastroCompletoUsuario");
            }

        }



        private void FindFileSizes(List<TB_IMAGEN_PERFIL> imgs)
        {
            foreach (var img in imgs)
            {
                // é preciso converter o caminho relativo da URL em um caminho físico no servidor
                var serverPath = Server.MapPath(img.Url);
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(serverPath))
                {
                    img.Size = new System.IO.FileInfo(serverPath).Length;
                }
            }
        }
        //::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Em UsuarioAplicacao(); tem um método que faz uma consulta trazendo os dados de 1 usuário.

na View tenho

@model Projeto.WebSite.Models.HomeViewModel

Mais não consigo acessar a tabela, como ficaria isso?

Comment: Posta o código do listar por Id e também o código do `tbuscar.ListarTodos();` pra poder ver como os dados estão vindo do banco, pois será necessário manipulá-los para retornar no formato que suas views espera os dados.

Comment: Também modificaria sua viewmodel para não ter uma lista de dados de usuário, mas sim apenas os dados de um usuário:  ao invés de `public List<Generico.Dominio.TB_USUARIO> TabelaUsuario { get; set; }` eu faria ` public Generico.Dominio.TB_USUARIO TabelaUsuario { get; set; }` ... na verdade eu criaria uma outra classe Usuario apenas com os dados pertinentes para a view... mas isso não é tão importante no seu caso, pois você não está enviando isso via JSON, já que está tratando apenas no servidor...

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente mudaria sua classe do view model para:

```
public class HomeViewModel
{

    public HomeViewModel()
    {
        // apenas para garantir que NUNCA seja nulo! Facilica código na view
        PreviewImages = new List<Generico.Dominio.TB_IMAGEN_PERFIL>();
        InitialPreviewConfigImages = new List<Generico.Dominio.TB_IMAGEN_PERFIL>();
        TabelaUsuario = new Generico.Dominio.TB_USUARIO();
    }

    //imagem do perfil do usuário 
    public List<Generico.Dominio.TB_IMAGEN_PERFIL> PreviewImages { get; set; }
    public List<Generico.Dominio.TB_IMAGEN_PERFIL> InitialPreviewConfigImages { get; set; }
    // não é necessário ser uma lista, já que é apenas um único usuário
    public Generico.Dominio.TB_USUARIO User { get; set; }
}
```

E no controller atribuiria o resultado da busca dos dados do usuário diretamente a essa variável:

```
public ActionResult ConsultaCadastroUsuarioCompleto(int id)
{
    //... código anterior continua o mesmo (try, etc.)
    var tbuscar = new UsuarioAplicacao();
    TB_USUARIO usuario = tbuscar.ListarPoId(id);

    var model = new HomeViewModel
    {
        User = usuario,
        PreviewImages = new List<Generico.Dominio.TB_IMAGEN_PERFIL> {
            new Generico.Dominio.TB_IMAGEN_PERFIL { Id = 1, Url = Url.Content("~/Content/img/galeriaimagens/sl1.jpg") },
//etc. o resto do código será idêntico...
```

**View Fortemente Tipada (com modelo)**

Se estiver usando um modelo fortemente tipado, você acessa os dados do usuário na view através do campo `Model.User` (ou outro nome que você criar). Como é fortemente tipado, você terá, inclusive complementação de código para facilitar a programação. Estude um pouco da sintaxe [Razor do .NET](https://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-c) para ficar familiarizado em como embutir código no meio do HTML. É muito gratificante. Bem mais eficiente do que soluções com PHP, pois a sintaxe é muito mais limpa, embora o conceito seja praticamente o mesmo.

```
@model Projeto.WebSite.Models.HomeViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
@* Para exibir o nome do usuário, por exemplo *@
<label>@Model.User.Name</label>
@* Não coloque ; ao final do model.User.Name senão vai ser considerado um ';' do html e não da linguagem *@
```

Note que a propriedade `Name` de `@Model.User.Name` pode ter outro nome na sua classe TBUSUARIO, cujo código não foi postado (muito menos o código da rotina que, efetivamente, lê esses dados do banco)

**View com dados dinâmicos (ViewBag)**

Se estiver usando `ViewBag` mude o controller para:

```
//...
var tbuscar = new UsuarioAplicacao();
TB_USUARIO usuario = tbuscar.ListarPoId(id);

var model = new HomeViewModel
//...
// adiciona o model no campo dinâmico Model do ViewBag
ViewBag.Model = model;
// não precisa retornar o model no View() porque estamos usando ViewBag
return View();
```

Para facilitar a vida na view, crie uma variável para receber os dados do modelo do `ViewBag` já no tipo `HomeViewModel`:

```
@using Meu.Namespace.Onde.Se.Encontra.HomeViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    // estou assumindo 
    var model = ViewBag.Model as HomeViewModel;
}
@* Para exibir o nome do usuário, por exemplo *@
<label>@model.User.Name</label>
@* Não coloque ; ao final do model.User.Name senão vai ser considerado um ';' do html e não da linguagem *@
```

Nota: substitua `Meu.Namespace.Onde.Se.Encontra.HomeViewModel` pelo namespace onde está a classe HomeViewModel!

Comment: Fiz o ajuste do código e postei ele na pergunta, mais não consigo pegar os dados na view, agradeço

Comment: @itasouza eu já mostrei como acessar os dados na View com o `@model Projeto.WebSite.Models.HomeViewModel` (fortemente tipada). Basta usar `@Model.User` que vai acessar os dados colocados em User. Mas o ideal era que você colocasse o código da rotina que pega os dados do usuário. Essa rotina pode estar com problema e retornando nulo! Vou atualizar o código para dar o exemplo fortemente tipado tb do uso da view